# Efficient Delete in Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate

I know that the following code will delete the record with id = 5 from database:

```
 Query query = session.createQuery("delete from Class where id = 5");
 query.executeUpdate();
```

But before i delete it, need to save this record's data in a variable.
So I want to select id = 5, and after some code, I delete it.
It's not efficient if i use two distinct query for them. Because in this way we search database for this item two times.

```
query = session.createQuery("from Class where id = 5");
//somecode
query = session.createQuery("delete Class where id = 5");
...
```

So i need a more efficient way to do this, and do it better.

Comment: It would be nice to explain why you think this is not a good way of coding it.  Otherwise it just seems like another "give me code that works" question.

Comment: yes, it's right. i did'n want to code like them, because, it must search in database 2 times.
but in the answers right method for this task is explained.

Comment: I know, however my point still stands, you state that its a bad idea to do it that way but never explained why you thought that.

Comment: @JonTaylor he said: `Because in this way we search database for this item two times.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to create query to delete a record.

```
query = session.createQuery("from Class where id = 5");
List list=query.list();
if(list.size()!=0)
 {
   ClassName obj = (ClassName)list.get(0);
   session.delete(obj);
  }
```

Comment: In addition, if this 'id' field is the @Id you can use session.get() to obtain your object in place of session.createQuery.

Answer (score 3):

Hibernate has a `Session.delete()` method. Use it if you already have a reference to the entity to remove. No need for a query.

This would also apply the potential cascades configured on associations, which a delete query does not.